# How to run a continuous loop until a value in the correct range has been entered

Tags: java, eclipse, input, while-loop

I need to Write a Java application which takes a number as input from the user and validates the input to ensure it is between 1 and 10. If the input is not in the correct range the application should
use a loop to continue asking the user for input until a value in the correct range has been
entered.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Number {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int j = 0;
        int J = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        J = input.nextInt();

    while(J > 10){

        j = input.nextInt();//read input from user
        System.out.println();

        if (j >=1 && j <=10 ) {
            System.out.println("Validated input: " + j);
            input.close();          
        }//end if statement

        else {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
            j = input.nextInt();
        }//end else statement

    }//end while loop       

    }//end main method

}//end class
```

I can get the code to work without the while loop but obviously it doesn't run continuously, with what I have done the question appears and you enter a number twice before the question appears again and there is an error with the validation message.

So my question is: "How do I get the while loop to run correctly, I probably haven't it wrote correctly so could someone help me please"

I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] use a loop to continue asking the user for input until a value in the
>   correct range has been entered.

```
while(j < 1 || j > 10)
```

That's pretty much it. Print the instruction withih the loop only. There's no need to have the same line twice. And get rid of that `if/else`. Your loop is already checking the condition. As soon as you leave it, the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of what you need to do. Also make sure in the future you name the parameters reasonably as opposed to i , j, x. For example in this case you would like to name it inputNumber or something similar.

```
print 'Please insert number'

int input = scanner.next

While (input not in range) {
 print 'error please input number in range'
 input = scanner.next
}

...process
exit
```